# How to compress files in angular 2 in production build

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

After generating the build using `ng build --aot false`, scripts.dc25b54b2f47c69ec8fe.bundle.js size is 4.5mb and main.ddd0054a477c4ef4343c.bundle.js is 2mb. It's taking lot of time to load  the page more than 3 minutes.

Comment: You're using the Angular CLI and I am not sure how much 
 performance optimization it does by default. You can always eject the webpack configuration and optimize it yourself. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject. Maybe implement treeshaking or code splitting. Also, you should use GZIP on your web server.

Comment: So, you have a lot of scripts? Don't use as many scripts, and it won't be as large. There is simply not enough information in the question to do anything other than give general advice.

Comment: Why don't you lazy load your modules? It won't download the whole files, it'll be divided into small chunks, Todd Motto has a great article about that. https://toddmotto.com/lazy-loading-angular-code-splitting-webpack